# SkipToken method for microsoft-graph inaccessible

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch some events from outlook/office365 calendar using microsoft-graph. As I noticed from the result, the number of events retrieved is 200, but the number of events from calendar is more. So, based on the informations from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events?tabs=csharp I tried to fetch the events in batches until @odata.deltaLink tag is received and tell me to stop because there are no other events. The problem here is that I can't use SkipToken(...) method in order to know from what point should I receive the remaining events.

I have installed 1.17.0 microsoft-graph version(Published data: Friday, August 16, 2019 (8/16/2019)).

I used the following code to retrieve the first batch of events:

```
var events = await graphClient.Me.CalendarView.Delta()
                                   .Request(calendarInterval)
                                   .Header("Prefer", "odata.track-changes")
                                   .GetAsync();
```

From "events" I got events.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"] in order to use it for a new call.

From events.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"] I got skiptoken code in order to use it for the following call:

```
var delta = await graphClient.Me.CalendarView
    .Delta()
    .Request()
    .Header("Prefer","odata.track-changes")
    .SkipToken("R0usmci39OQxqJrxK4")
    .GetAsync();
```

R0usmci39OQxqJrxK4 -> is the code extracted from events.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"]

The big problem here is that I cannot use SkipToken() method.
I have the folloing error and I don't know why because it is used the last version of microsoft-graph.

ERROR: Error    CS1061  'IEventDeltaRequest' does not contain a definition for 'SkipToken' and no accessible extension method 'SkipToken' accepting a first argument of type 'IEventDeltaRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same result by passing in a requestOption as follows

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$skiptoken", "R0usmci39OQxqJrxK4")
};

var delta = await graphClient.Me.CalendarView
    .Delta()
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .Header("Prefer","odata.track-changes")
    .GetAsync();
```